# Django - NoReverseMatch Error when using named URL with parameter

Tags: django, urlconf

I'm trying to build this link using a named URL with a parameter:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/wakemeup/admin/list/colegio

The parameter is the string after `.../list/` (in this case "colegio").  I have a `print()` statement in the `admin_list` view, which shows the parameter is getting extracted correctly.  However, when I try to build the URL:

```
<a href="{% url 'wakemeup:admin_list' list_type=colegio %}">Colegios</a>
```

I get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /wakemeup/admin/list/colegio
Reverse for 'admin_list' with keyword arguments '{'list_type': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['wakemeup/admin/list/(?P<list_type>\\w+)$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/wakemeup/admin/list/colegio
Django Version: 2.0.1
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'admin_list' with keyword arguments '{'list_type': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['wakemeup/admin/list/(?P<list_type>\\w+)$']
```

**views.py**

```
def admin_list(request, list_type):
    print(list_type)
    return index(request)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^admin/list/(?P<list_type>\w+)$', views.admin_list, name="admin_list"),
```

I also tried using an unnamed parameter, but that did not work.

Comment: Try something simple, like `{% url 'wakemeup:admin_list' list_type='colegio' %}`

Comment: Samsonite!  I was way off...I knew it started with an S though.  

Thanks a lot, that fixed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To confirm the answer following your comment, remember to correctly format your template url kwargs as strings;

```
{% url 'wakemeup:admin_list' list_type='colegio' %}
```

For further reading the docs on URLs are here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/